Understand power rating in layman terms
I have recently started the chapter of electricity of class 8. I am not understanding the concept of power rating of appliances. When we say that a bulb is rated 220V-100W, which means, according to what I understand, that a total work of 220 Joules is being done to send unit charge (Coulomb) since:
$$1V = \frac{1\ Joule}{1\ Coulomb}$$
The bulb, in turn, does a total work of 100 Joules in one second. But since 220 Joules of work sends a CHARGE of 1 Coulomb, how does the bulb get ENERGY. Where does the transition from the charge to energy occur?
Please explain in layman terms for an 8th grader.

First of all, how did you get 220 Joules?

If you have already put in some effort into figuring this out for yourself, you should show that. Your question is very basic and is covered in many sources, not just your textbook. There are a LOT of layman explanations out there if you would look. However, what is most pressing is that your question is internally confused; you already know that the bulb is getting 100 Joules of energy every second from the electricity that is flowing through it, so your question needs to be reworded.

Your outlet supplies needed current while holding at 220V. Power is voltage times current. So a 100W bulb draws 100/220 amps.

@JonCuster I appreciate your answer but It would be great if you could explain a bit more deeply. Such as, what do you mean by an an output supply, and it holding at 220v. Also what does it mean to draw 100/120 amps. Kinldy understand since I am stil a schoolboy

The utility puts out electricity at 220V (alternating current). The line to your house will carry 100 amps or more to supply everything. The bulb is made to connect to a 220V supply, and is designed to draw enough amperage to use 100W of power. Since Watts = Voltage*Current, the current it will draw is Current=Watts/Voltage. That is all.

One major doubt. You said that the utility puts out electricity at 220V. 220V describes that it does work into giving charge, whereas electricity is a form of energy. My doubt that I am holding from the beginning is that how does charge, being the flow of electrons, relate to electricity, a form of energy.

Please clarify what you mean by "transition from the charge to energy". The charges in a circuit are not converted to energy. They flow back into the negative terminal.

@naturallyInconsistent I think it is unfair to encourage the questioner to show his working. As soon as he does that, there are people here that will take that as grounds to close the question on the grounds it is a "check my working" type question. Personally, I think asking for or producing numeric examples helps clarify the concepts, but unfortunately any question that defines variables and defines numeric values for those variables is instantly taken to be a homework question by those people that like closing questions, so you are giving bad advice in the context of how things are here.

No tutor would ask "how does a bulb get energy from an electric circuit" as a homework question for an 8th grader. The answer is non intuitive and most adults would get the answer wrong. The energy is actually transferred in the electromagnetic field. Veritasium has done a series of videos on just this question. https://www.bing.com/videos/riverview/relatedvideo?q=veritasium+electricty&mid=7B7502F44F8FF35F6A6C7B7502F44F8FF35F6A6C&FORM=VIRE This is clearly not a homework question and it is an important concept, so I have voted to reopen the question.

@KDP the comment is meant to ask him what sources he had consulted, not what numerical values example he had tried.

@KDP "most adults would get the answer wrong" Citation needed.

You stated that when one coulomb of charge passes through the bulb then $220\,\rm J$ of electrical energy is converted into heat and light.
This is a correct statement but you must now realise that it takes $11/5=2.2$ seconds for one coulomb of charge to pass through the bulb.
Thus in one second the energy dissipated in the bulb is $220/2.2=100\,\rm J$ and this is the power of the bulb in watts.
Here is another way of analysing the situation.
In one second $5/11$ coulomb of charge pass through the bulb and so the electrical energy dissipated in the bulb is $220\times 5/11= 100 \rm\, J$.
As power is energy per second and measured in watts, the power rating of the bulb is $100\,\rm W$.
